# distinct values of different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm not sure it's possible.

I have a table with 3 columns, and I want to get different values of each one, there is an example:

```
A      B        C
--------------------
a1     b1       c1
a1     b2       c2
a1     b3       c1
```

The expected result is:

```
A      B       C
-----------------
a1     b1      c1
       b2      c2
       b3
```

So, it will be the union of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM myTable
SELECT DISTINCT B FROM myTable
SELECT DISTINCT C FROM myTable
```

Using UNION I get the result in one column.

Is this posible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT COALESCE( a, '' ) AS a,
       COALESCE( b, '' ) AS b,
       COALESCE( c, '' ) AS c
FROM ( SELECT a,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a ) AS recordNumber
       FROM ( SELECT a
              FROM myTable
              GROUP BY a
            ) aFinder
     ) aNumberedFinder
FULL JOIN ( SELECT b,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY b ) AS recordNumber
            FROM ( SELECT b
                   FROM myTable
                   GROUP BY b
                 ) bFinder
          ) bNumberedFinder ON bNumberedFinder.recordNumber = aNumberedFinder.recordNumber
FULL JOIN ( SELECT c,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c ) AS recordNumber
            FROM ( SELECT c
                   FROM myTable
                   GROUP BY c
                 ) cFinder
          ) cNumberedFinder ON cNumberedFinder.recordNumber = aNumberedFinder.recordNumber
                            OR cNumberedFinder.recordNumber = bNumberedFinder.recordNumber;
```

This statement starts with the following subquery...

```
SELECT a
FROM myTable
GROUP BY a
```

This subquery produces a list of the unique values in field `a`.  The following subquery reproduces this list with record (aka row) numbers...

```
SELECT a,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a ) AS recordNumber
FROM ( SELECT a
       FROM myTable
       GROUP BY a
     ) aFinder
```

Similar subqueries are used to produce numbered lists of the unique values in fields `b` and `c`.

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` (abbreviated here to `FULL JOIN`) is then performed between the lists for `a` and `b`, with their record numbers being used as the common / joining value.

Note : An `INNER JOIN` would only have returned as many records as there are in the shorter list of the two.  A `LEFT JOIN` would only have been effective if the list on the left of the `JOIN` were of greater or longer length than the list on the right.  Similar logic applies to the usage of a `RIGHT JOIN`.  A `FULL JOIN` will join the two lists in the manner of a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` irrespective of which list is longer.

A `FULL JOIN` is then performed between the above joined dataset and the list for `c` where it finds a common value in either list.

The values of `a`, `b` and `c` are then selected from the finally joined dataset, with the `COALESCE()` function replacing the occurrence of any `NULL` values, such as those generated by the joining process, with the empty string (`''`)

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Appendix**

My statement was tested against a database created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    a   VARCHAR( 5 ),
    b   VARCHAR( 5 ),
    c   VARCHAR( 5 )
);
INSERT INTO myTable ( a,
                      b,
                      c
                    )
VALUES ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1' ),
       ( 'a1', 'b2', 'c2' ),
       ( 'a1', 'b3', 'c1' );
```

**Further Reading**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql (on using the `COALESCE()` function in Transact-SQL)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp (on the various types of horizontal `JOIN` - the Venn diagram is useful)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx (on using `OUTER JOIN` in SQL-Server)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql (on using `ROW_NUMBER()` in Transact-SQL)

Comment: Code tested and corrected version posted.  Explanation underway.